# I can't scroll in any UWP Application

Tags: windows, windows-10, scrolling, gui, uwp

for some time now I am unable to scroll in UWP apps. Wheather it be small dialoges (like the emoji picker) or normal UWP windows, like `SystemSettings.exe`.
I honestly have no idea where I could start with diagnostics and maybe you got an idea on why it doesn't work for me?

My scroll wheel functions properly and I never had any other issues with scrolling in non-UWP apps.
I always have to use the scroll bar to scroll in UWP apps and middle clicking to scroll is also not possible in UWP apps.

I'm using Windows 10 21H1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to a third party application, called [AltDrag](https://github.com/stefansundin/altdrag) and the feature to scroll inactive windows. Disabling it resolves the scrolling problem.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/stefansundin/altdrag/issues/147)